# How to install google-api-python-client via terminal

Tags: python, google-api

i'n trying to install google-api-python-client package, using terminal and

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

the same result for

```
sudo -H  pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

also I found, that someone recommends to use such approach:

```
sudo chown -R zkid18 /Users/zkid18/Library/Logs/pip
chown: /Users/zkid18/Library/Logs/pip: No such file or directory
```

and

```
sudo chown -R zkid18 /Users/zkid18/Library/Cashes/pip
chown: /Users/zkid18/Library/Cashes/pip: No such file or directory
```

Tje same result, when I'm installing via Pycharm
My exception

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 736, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 742, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/**init**.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-uxDRkx-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install with virtualenv

```
virtualenv temp
source temp/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

or ignore Six

```
sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client --ignore-installed six
```

Comment: Is it possible to install without venv?